# How to get live reloading in AWS Cloud 9

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

How do I get AWS Cloud 9 to live reload my web page when I save a file similar to BrowserSync or LiveReload.

Answer (score 3):

By default AWS Cloud 9 will refresh the preview when you hit `Ctrl + Enter`. But this can be set to live reload in `Preferences... User settings... Run... Preview... When saving reload preview` and setting it to "Always".

Comment: Now, if only it could live reload on without saving I'd really be in business :)

Comment: Well, the "live reload" sort of happens when auto-save is enabled.